# I'm trying to create a temporary array to store strings with malloc using a double pointer but i'm running into overwrite of my previous strings

Tags: c, string, input, malloc, double-pointer

This is what i'm trying to do right now but I don't know if this is this correct way to do it since I started learning C recently

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char** input = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
    char buffer[10];


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
        *(input+i) = buffer;
        printf("%s",*(input));
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s",*(input+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In my head the logic seems fine but I don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: You've allocated memory to hold 5 pointers to char arrays. You have not allocated any corresponding char arrays. Other than your single local char array buffer which can hold one string of up to 9 chars, you have no place to put any strings.

Comment: You have allocated an array of 5 character pointers. Now ask yourself *what do those point to*?

Comment: Note: `*(input+i)` would be better as `input[i]`

Comment: If there isn't a reason that you are trying to use dynamic memory, for this small case, you might want to consider using a 2 dimensional local array. Or you might want to start with using the local 2d array to get that working, and then modify it to use dynamic allocation. Not sure if that would be helpful for you or not.

Comment: I like C. But: is C really the language you want to do this in? This kind of string handling is most complicated and more error-prone in C than it is in basically any other major language. Really, the weakest point of C, and you dive right into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried to print the address for each input index using `printf("%p", *(input + i));` You will notice that all addresses are the same.

That happens because the pointers are pointed to the same array that you have defined before executing the loop, so you are just overriding the same array for each `fgets()`

You can fix this by creating a new array with a new reference for each iteration like this:

```cpp
    char** input = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char *buffer = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
        *(input+i) = buffer;
        printf("%s",*(input+i));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on with your code. In your example you allocated space for 5 *pointers* to chars, i.e., 5 pointers which could point to strings.

You use the following code: `*(input+i) = buffer;`. What it really does, it assigns address of array *buffer* to your pointers. It is the same address for all your pointers. The *fgets* function always overrides values in this array, as a result, all your pointers point to the same string, which was
read last.

I guess, what you really wanted, is to read a string and store it. For that reason you need space for every string separately. Before doing it, however, you should remember, that strings in 'c' must be terminated by '\0', which takes an additional character position in the string. So, you need

1. `char buffer[11] = {0};` initialized to all zeros (at least the last element).
2. `fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);` same way as you had it.
3. A simple trick:

```
 *(input+i) = malloc(11);
 strcpy(*(input+1), buffer);
```

Now you have every new string copied in a new location in memory and therefore preserved.

Comment: would you please tell what is difference between int (*a)[5], and int* a[5], what i searched its regarding subscripts priority and all but i dont quite get it and also what does char const *argv[]mean

Comment: @Raon you should ask a separate question about it.